# Is there any way to merge object properties as follow?

Tags: javascript

I want to refactor initial object in JavaScript to refactored object as below example.is there any way to do it with Lodash or in plain JavaScript?

```
const initialObject = {
    status: 'success',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'price',
            value: 12,
        },
        {
            name: 'remain',
            value: 45,
        },
    ],
};

const RefactoredObject = {
    status: 'success',
    fields: [
        {
            price: 12,
        },
        {
            remain: 45,
        },
    ],
};
```

Comment: you can use array map to transform the fields array

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have one object with all properties instead of an array where each object contains a single property?

Comment: do you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here

```js
const initialObject = {
    status: 'success',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'price',
            value: 12,
        },
        {
            name: 'remain',
            value: 45,
        },
    ],
};

const result = {
    ...initialObject,
    fields: initialObject.fields.map(({ name, value }) => ({ [name]: value })),
};
console.log(result);
```